# How to pass a row from a matrix to a new array in C

Tags: c, arrays, matrix

So in c I have a data matrix that is n x m. How can I extract a single row to pass it to a new variable. My python code looks like this:

new_var = data[i, :]

Please help me translate into C.

My way is

```
  int i = rand(num_rows);
    double new_var[num_cols];
    for (j = 0; j < num_cols; j++)
    {
        new_var[j] = data[i][j];
    }
```

Please comment. 
Many thanks

Comment: You're using `rand()` incorrectly, but you copy the row correctly.

Comment: sounds like x-y. `double *new_var=data[i]` works most of the time, unless you do need deep copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is correct. But I don't get what you are trying to do with this -

```
  int i = rand(num_rows); // using rand like this is incorrect syntax.
```

If you want a random number between `0` to `num_rows`. Correct will be -

```
  int i = rand()%num_rows;
```

See here how  to use [`rand`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_rand.htm).